# TypeError: Input must be a list / sequence of tuple-likes

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

So Now I think am on the right sequence

so from previous question [How to modify pandas Dataframe and how to Interact with plot dash gui frameworkout html core components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007766/how-to-modify-pandas-dataframe-and-how-to-interact-with-plot-dash-gui-frameworko)

I noticed that using `set_value` is the best way to update/modify specific cells in `dataframe` ,so I tried to use this code

```
values.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(values.index)

ext_sites.set_value(values.index, 'Pending  ', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
```

By the way I used to convert `tuple` values into `MultiIndex`

but I find this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/Gov-Trac-Tool/updateMyDF.py", line 34, in <module>
    values.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(values.index)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 383, in from_tuples
    raise TypeError('Input must be a list / sequence of tuple-likes.')
TypeError: Input must be a list / sequence of tuple-likes.
```

how ever it work when I specify the row index only like this

`ext_sites.set_value(800, 'Pending  ', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')`

So  am I on the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution of your code doesn't reach *ext_sites.set_value(...)*.
The error in your code occurs one line earlier:

```
values.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(values.index)
```

what is clearly written in your Traceback.

Take a look at documentation of *pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples*.
It contains:

```
tuples : list / sequence of tuple-likes
```

Apparently `values.index` is not any list / sequence of tuple-likes,
so *Pandas* complains about this.
Maybe you have a "normal" index (not MultiIndex)?

By the way: Your variable has name `values`. It is a bad habit to
choose variable names overlapping with method names (the same pertains
to column names). Use some other name.

Another bad habit: Column names should not contain trailing spaces,
like `'Pending  '` in your code.
They should not contain also **initial** spaces.

Comment: thanks a lot your answer is actually logically right.....
Almost respect this.....
thanks a lot bro it's helps me a lot